# fork without exec, and pthread_mutex_t used by shared object

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads, posix, fork

I'm working with a web server project that performs a `fork` without an `exec`. The program depends upon OpenSSL, and OpenSSL needs a number of locks (`CRYPTO_NUM_LOCKS` to be exact, which is about 40 at the moment). The locks are typically `pthread_mutex_t` on Linux, and they are installed/created on the main thread before any threads are created.

`fork` creates a new process. However, after the `fork`, the handles used in the mutex are shallow copied. That is, they have the same bits but I don't believe they have a useful value in the context of the new process.

I think the general problem is that of thread and fork safety in a shared object. The [OpenSSL wiki](http://wiki.openssl.org/) page on `libcrypto` discusses [thread and fork safety](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Libcrypto_API#Fork_Safety), and I'm not sure how to address some of the problems.

Is there a way to specify that a library (such as OpenSSL) should be re-initialized on `fork`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mutexes won't be valid across the `fork` unless you put them in shared memory and initialize the mutex attribute with `pthread_mutexattr_setpshared` set to PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED.

It's not clear if you are forking and then creating threads or creating the threads and then forking.  If the latter, then fork will only apply to the thread that calls fork.  None of the other threads are created in the new process.

If you are forking and then threading and the mutexes are meant to only apply to the child process and its threads then just create them after the fork.